# Any phrase indexing capability in solr

Tags: solr

Is there a tokenizer/filter in Solr which can index some phrases (I guess in the form of file) as a single token? Also any advice in terms of where to put this one in the analyzer chain would be great to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SynonymFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) should be of help to you. Here is the example from that page:

```
#Explicit mappings match any token sequence on the LHS of "=>"
#and replace with all alternatives on the RHS.  These types of mappings
#ignore the expand parameter in the schema.
#Examples:
i-pod, i pod => ipod
sea biscuit, sea biscit => seabiscuit
```

At index time, the phrases on the left get replaced with the single token on the right. Store your mappings in a file named `syn.txt` and you can have the analyzer chain as follows (again from the solr wiki link):

```
<fieldtype name="syn" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer>
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syn.txt" 
                  ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

Comment: Thanks but synonym isn't exactly what I am looking for. For example, I want to index "new york" as a single word so that "new" or "york" won't be matched.

Comment: If you keep `new york => newyork` in syn.txt and don't split it to create any more tokens further down in your index-time analyzer chain, then a search for `new` or `york` won't match. However to match the document containing `new york` the user has to issue a phrase query "new york" and you should use the synonym filter at query time too. And the returned document will contain `newyork` without the space. BTW, I searched `new` in google and it gave `new york times` in top 10, so it isn't too bad after all? :-)

Comment: I tried this. My finding is that Solr still seems to index "new" and "york" separately? I tried both expand=true and expand=false, no changes? Any insight what went wrong?

Comment: If you are using the analysis tool, then it highlights a match, but if you actually index a document and search on the field for 'new' or 'york' it doesn't match.

Comment: Ok. Let me try with clean environment. I am using SOLR 4.1 and I wasn't very specific in my previous comment: I found "newyork" is indexed as well as new & york. If I test "tiger => lion", then only lion is indexed and tiger is gone so I am wondering if it is something to do with phrase handling in SFF. Anyway I will test again.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a [TokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#TokenFilterFactories) for this.

If you want to detect sentences as well, then you can look at solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory.

If the input is in a specific pattern you can use solr.PatternTokenizerFactory.

If you want to index the whole input as one field you can use solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory.